# Breakpoints in Microsoft Fluent UI Northstar

Tags: fluentui-react

Is there any way of using breakpoints in Microsoft's Fluent UI Northstar? While I acknowledge that they don't support mobile yet, even on desktop you have be responsive to window size changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Fluent UI React library doesn't support this feature, but I was successful using [react-responsive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive) to change my layout depending on screen size.